# Pass custom prop from index.html to actual component in stencil.js

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

I am facing an issue related to communication between index.html tag to stencil component

this is my index.html

```
<html>
<body>
   <my-component prop="test"></my-component>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the actual stencil component's .tsx file

my-component.tsx

```
export class MyComponent {
@Prop() prop:string;

componentDidLoad() {
console.log(this.prop)
}
render() {
    return <div>
       <second-component
           prop = {this.prop}
       ></second-component> 
    </div>
  }
}
```

In short I want to pass prop from index.html to my-component that passes the same prop to second-component?
How can I implement it?

Comment: That seems to be correct, what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: I was trying to pass it in an config object but anyways the problem is solved. Thank you @RienNeVaPlu͢s